# Coilgun capacitor reverse voltage in my schematic?

Tags: voltage, electrolytic-capacitor

I'm going to build a coilgun and have thought about all possible problems, which I solved except the reverse voltage problem. I designed a schematic based on some other schematics I found online. My question is whether the capacitor in my schematic will be able to explode due to reverse voltage or not.

It is a polarized electrolytic capacitor rated for 200v with a capacity of 2400uf (4 x 600uf in parallel). I calculated a graph of the current and the capacitor's voltage, which showed me the voltage of the capacitor will become negative before the current goes through zero, which would deactivate the thyristor which will be used to trigger the circuit. I've added a diode with a resistor next to the coil to absorb the back emf, and a diode with a resistor next to the capacitor to absorb the reversed voltage which could be created across the capacitor.

The 120V DC will be generated using a boost converter with a constant current function that I will be using at around 200mA

Will the capacitor be damaged or not in the following circuit and why? If so, can it be fixed by reducing the resistance of the 2 ohm resistor next to the capacitor?

The graph shows the voltage across the capacitor in red with a peak voltage of 120v and the current through the coil in blue with a peak value of 80A. The total time plotted is 15ms.[image][image]

Comment: A series diode from the cap will prevent cap back voltage - with a loss of a percent or so of peak power. | Guesstimate: The parallel diode will dissipate ABOUT  2 x Ireverse when back current starts to flow or overall most of the energy left in the inductor when the diode starts to conduct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "My question is whether the capacitor in my schematic will be able to explode due to reverse voltage or not. "

**Yes it can explode** when the coil current starts to decline significantly or when the reverse voltage exceeds 5% of the rated forward voltage.

You must avoid a reverse voltage being applied to the e-cap.

The phase relationship of the RLC circuit is under your control to maximize power transfer and impedance of load.

The design could use a reverse power diode across the e-Cap. But I did not analyze the entire design for efficiency.

Comment: So just removing the 2 ohm resistor next to the capacitor will solve the problem? Any idea on how much current the power diode will need to handle? In all the schematics online they don't seem to have any protection for reverse voltage, so that made me wonder.

Comment: cap current indicates about 80% Imax on graph. Duration depends on L/Rtotal.  Online schematics with what skill ?